# Module "AspNetCoreModule" could not be found for non-Core app

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, .net-framework-version

My Solution has projects with a lot of database code, and a web site, all in .Net Framework 4.5. I just added a new Core 2.0 web project from the VS2017 template to the solution, which runs OK.

Now I cannot run the old web site by setting it as the Startup Project. Although it does NOT use Core, but the old .Net Framework 4.5, it causes an error message:

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
Module "AspNetCoreModule" could not be found
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried installing the ASP.NET Core Hosting Bundle anyway?

Comment: No, because that would mean I have to install that on the production server too. Is it not possible to add a Core project to a solution without messing up older .Net Framework projects?

Comment: It generally should be possible, but I am just wondering if maybe your setup on your development machine is confused. Do you have the latest SDK installed?

Comment: @poke Probably not. This is a 10-year old project. Every once in a while I upgrade, e.g. to a higher .Net Framework, but rather not too often, because we don't want to break things. We will certainly not upgrade the 4.5 site to Core.

Comment: I never suggested doing that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I archived the solution to SVN right before and after adding the new Core project, I found that the problem must be in solution file:

```
.vs/config/applicationhost.config
```

where there are several references to this Core module, even if I unload (made not-available) the new Core project. Only after closing VS, removing this config file and restarting VS, the FW 4.5 site will work again.

I stopped debugging the 4.5 project, reloaded the Core project, and started debugging the 4.5 site. Works OK.

I stopped debugging the 4.5 project, made the Core project the startup project, and started debugging. The Core site works.

I repeated to debug the 4.5 project: working.

Conclusion: removing the application.host file fixed it. Poke was right, the setup got confused.

Comment: Not sure how VS modified `applicationHost.config` when you created the .NET Core project, but clearly that modification was wrong (can be a bug of VS).