# Module "AspNetCoreModule" could not be found - In a non .NET Core web app

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, iis-10, .net-framework-version

I have an older ASP.NET Webforms application on my machine that I cannot get working. When I run the site, I get this error:

[image]

I am not sure why it is looking for `AspNetCoreModule` when the framework for this project is .NET 4.8. I am not using any .NET Core projects in this solution.

I do have .NET Core installed on my machine because I have been developing Blazor Server applications, however, that should not affect this solution. Also, I have the proper older frameworks installed because I do have other older projects using 4.7 and 4.8 what work.

Has anyone come across this issue and know how to solve it?

I have also seen this post in StackOverflow however, it is not the same situation as my current code: [module-aspnetcoremodule-could-not-be-found-for-non-core-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54711386/module-aspnetcoremodule-could-not-be-found-for-non-core-app)

I have checked all configs in the solution as well as the application config for this solution and nowhere do I see any references to .NET Core

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: At which location on IIS did you publish this ASP.NET 4.x web app? It can easily inherit the .NET Core specific settings from IIS configuration.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  The code is in GIT and the repository was cloned from there.  There are no references to .NET core

Comment: Since you seem to be unfamiliar with project settings that you should reveal, run a report and share as part of the question, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/vs-diagnostics.html#

Comment: Thanks for the link however, not much info.  The is the Project Diag results:
Scan the folder C:\......\myProject for project files.
0 project(s) are detected.
Zero or multiple C# project files are detected. Currently VSDiag only supports a single C# project.

There are 26 projects in this solution.

I also did a .NetCore Diag:
System Time: 1/24/2024 3:29:31 PM
Processor Architecture: AMD64
OS: Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.19045.0
Server Type: IIS

Scan 42 installed module(s).
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an .

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by going into the project in IIS and going to the Modules section.  For some reason AspNetCoreModule and AspNetCoreModuleV2 were in the list.  They were not there originally and not sure why/how they were added.  Once I removed them, my site started working with no issues.

I hope this is helpful to someone searching in the future.

Thanks to all that replied.

Comment: That explained a lot behind the scene. You must have installed ASP.NET Core hosting bundle for IIS somehow, but later uninstalled it. However, the relevant module references were left behind. That breaks every web apps (and Jexus Manager diagnostics) then and your manual cleanup is the only option to bring them back to health.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I will be using that diagnostic tool in the future if needed